# How to fix OutOfMemory happened with Lettuce Redis

Tags: spring-webflux, netty, lettuce, spring-data-redis-reactive

We are using spring data Redis Reactive(with lettuce). Application instance freezed with OutOfMemory Error. Analysis of the heap dump shows that 128 instances of **DefaultEventExecutor** occupied the maximum of the heap space (*DefaultEventExecutor.taskQueue* holds the *io.lettuce.core.RedisPublisher$OnComplete* instances). How can I fix this?

Below is the thread pool configuration

```
clientConfigurationBuilder
.clientResources(ClientResources.builder().ioThreadPoolSize(128).computationThreadPoolSize(128).build())
.clientOptions(ClientOptions.builder().publishOnScheduler(true).build());
```

Note: Spring web flux is also being used in the same project.

Comment: Why do you have 128 io/compute threads? Lettuce is non-blocking, you shouldn't need that many threads unless you're running on a 128 core processor. Is it possible you're creating multiple client resources? Can you show more code of how this is used?